# WS Security Policy is coming in generated WSDL

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

We are developing a **Apache CXF SOAP MTOM** service to upload the documents to server.

As part of that we need to enable security in service. So we are using **WS-Security Policy** to enable security.

We have added below annotations in Service Interface and Service Implementation class also.

1. **@Policies({ @Policy(uri = "classpath:ut.policy.xml",
       placement = Policy.Placement.BINDING) })**

I have placed **ut.policy.xml** file both WEB-INF and src/resources folder also.

Below is the **cxf.xml**

```
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>

    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true" />
        <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="passwordCallback" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <p:policies ignoreUnknownAssertions="true" />
        <cxf:logging />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
<bean id="passwordCallback"
    class="com.uob.ewf.AuthenticationCallbackHandler" />
```

Still we are not able to generate WS-Security Policy in generated WSDL file. Please help us to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please help us on this.

Comment: Please help on this issue. Thank you